# SVN error on eclipse with Delete operation (aparently)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, svn

I have an Android project on Eclipse (STS) and it is giving me this error last time I tried to compile:

`The project was not built due to "SVN: '0x00000119: Delete' operation finished with error". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent`

Google was not very helpful.. Only 9 hits

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would discard your current project and rebuild the project files again, importing the codebase  :(

**Update:**
JohnEye recommends trying an svn cleanup first and this may solve your issue.  If not, see above.

Comment: That's just the "have you tried turn it off and on again?" of eclipse. But I would rather try something less _brutal_

Comment: This seemed to be the only solution :(

Comment: This proved to e the only solution for me as well. Fortunately it is still possible to commit the changes before deleting the project, so it will be up to date when you do a checkout.

Comment: I just found a possible solution, see my answer.

Comment: perfect! team -> cleanup / then clean project again

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, I disconnected and connected the project from the SVN.
In the project, right click, TEAM>Disconnect and the problem was solved

Answer (score 5):

I may have just found the answer. It is surprisingly simple, assuming you are using linux, navigate to the project directory (`cd ~/workspace/myProject`) and run `svn cleanup`

Solved the problem for me.

Edit: Just happened to me again and my solution worked as expected, so it probably was not just a random fluke.

Comment: possible this was a bug in svn tortoise before and has now been fixed.  Thanks for the update JohnEye

Comment: I have no way to confirm this, but if enough people bump it up I'll mark it as the valid answer.

Comment: I had the same problem, and it was caused by a conflict not being reported by eclipse. Cleaning the project before any SVN operation surely helped, but in the end i had to "replace with latest version" a whole module to see what it actually changes, and thats how i found the conflict.

Answer (score 2):

Had same issue. The work-around was to disconnect the project from SVN **(Team->Disconnect) (note: please make sure you don't delete .svn)** and refresh the project. Your are back on track, and you can reconnect to SVN once again.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the project and re-checking out has worked for a couple of hours, but then the problem returned (maybe I deleted stuff again or whatever). There's a bug track here: http://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SVNKIT-77

Answer (score 0):

SVN is a wonderful tool, if used correctly. Unfortunately when we use SVN incorrect, we run into such crazy issues.

The best way to fix issues like this,

1. Checkout Project again
2. Use meld and copy "ONLY" files, NOT "directories" from workspace to checkout folder.

If you copy folders, you will also end up copying .svn hidden folders and you will be in the same mess again. So create the folders manually.

One more, DONT waste your time trying to find ways to fix your svn issues. Just use the 2 step process above.

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering the same issue after importing the project from bitbucket repo. What worked for me was to disconnect the project and connect it again.

```
    1. Team->disconnect.
    2. Team->share project->Git->Use or create repository in parent folder->finish
```